# Create Index on new column for large table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle10g, database-performance

I have a table with over 10 million rows.  I created a new column on that table and then tried to index it:

```
create index myTable_idx_myColumn on myTable(myColumn);
```

That query timed out after about an hour.  I then retried it with the `NOLOGGING` option, and that completed successfully after about an hour.

Problem solved, right?  Unfortunately not, as that was just for the dev database.  The prod database has over 25 million rows, so ideally I'd like to find a faster solution before I create the index there to avoid unnecessary downtime.

What is strange to me is that from my understanding, Oracle doesn't include `null` values for indexes by default (which is what I want).  To me, that means it should just create a blank index since all the values in the new column are `null` when the index is created.  I get that it needs to check all 10 million rows to make sure they are `null`, but even that doesn't seem like it should take anywhere close to an hour...

**Is there a fast way to add an index to a new column (i.e. where all values are `null`) on a large table?**

Comment: Why would you need index on null only column? If you want all rows (rowids) in the index then you would need to create composite index, where at least one column is not null.

Comment: @clq The values are only null because it is a brand new column.  New rows will get values, and it will be common to query based on those values since it is a foreign key to another table.

Comment: There are many thinks you can do. There must be a reason why the index takes so long time to create. 25M is not a lot. Best if you ask your dba. :) One technical opton could be to run parallel index creation. One non technical option would be to schedule your create index statement and run over the weekend.

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to make it faster but they may not be necessary.

10 million rows is a relatively small number.  Although things could be different if the rows are extremely wide.  For performance issues it's often better to know the segment size than the row count.  The segment size and knowledge of your hardware will help you make very rough estimates.  For example, "the table is 100GB, the SAN reads single-threaded at 100MB/second, so it will take 17 minutes just to scan the table...".

```
--Find the segment size in gigabytes.
--No matter how many rows there are this may be the amount of I/O processed.
select sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 gb
from dba_segments
where segment_name = 'MYTABLE';
```

In this trivial example, 10 million rows are created in 5 seconds on my PC.

```
--Create table.
drop table myTable;
create table myTable(id number, myColumn varchar2(100)) nologging;

--Insert 10 million rows.  Takes 9 seconds on my PC.
begin
    for i in 1 .. 100 loop
        insert /*+ append */ into myTable
          select level, null from dual connect by level <= 100000;
        commit;
    end loop;
end;
/

--Create index.  Takes 5 seconds on my PC.
create index myTable_idx_myColumn on myTable(myColumn);
```

So what's happening on your machine?  To find out, first you need to find the SQL_ID for the `CREATE INDEX ...` statement.  While the index is building, run this:

```
--Find the SQL_ID.
select sql_id, sql_text, elapsed_time/1000000 seconds
from v$sql
where users_executing > 0
order by seconds desc;
```

There are plenty of ways to go from here, I prefer SQL Monitoring.  If the statement is running or was running "recently", the monitoring data should still be around.  Plug the SQL_ID into this SQL statement to get the report:

```
--Generate SQL Monitoring report.
--(This feature requires licensing, but if this is the first time you use it, it's
-- reasonable to consider this "testing".  Buy it if you like it.)
select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor('gb7tu2jpwng3q') from dual;
```

There's a lot of data in the report.  It takes a while to understand, but usually it will contain most of what you need to solve these kinds of problems.  First, look at the Activity (%) - which step is taking the longest?  Then look at the Details - what was it waiting for?  Look at the Read and Write bytes, are they reasonable for the hardware?

```
SQL Monitoring Report

SQL Text
------------------------------
create index myTable_idx_myColumn on myTable(myColumn)

Global Information
------------------------------
 Status              :  DONE                              
 Instance ID         :  1                                 
 Session             :  JHELLER (133:56633)               
 SQL ID              :  gb7tu2jpwng3q                     
 SQL Execution ID    :  16777216                          
 Execution Started   :  10/23/2015 00:34:32               
 First Refresh Time  :  10/23/2015 00:34:36               
 Last Refresh Time   :  10/23/2015 00:34:37               
 Duration            :  5s                                
 Module/Action       :  PL/SQL Developer/SQL Window - New 
 Service             :  orcl12                            
 Program             :  plsqldev.exe                      

Global Stats
================================================================================================
| Elapsed |   Cpu   |    IO    | Application | PL/SQL  | Buffer | Read | Read  | Write | Write |
| Time(s) | Time(s) | Waits(s) |  Waits(s)   | Time(s) |  Gets  | Reqs | Bytes | Reqs  | Bytes |
================================================================================================
|    4.72 |    2.67 |     1.84 |        0.21 |    0.00 |  15594 | 3904 | 312MB |   795 | 192MB |
================================================================================================

SQL Plan Monitoring Details (Plan Hash Value=564701026)
========================================================================================================================================================================================================
| Id |        Operation         |         Name         |  Rows   | Cost |   Time    | Start  | Execs |   Rows   | Read | Read  | Write | Write |  Mem  | Temp  | Activity |      Activity Detail       |
|    |                          |                      | (Estim) |      | Active(s) | Active |       | (Actual) | Reqs | Bytes | Reqs  | Bytes | (Max) | (Max) |   (%)    |        (# samples)         |
========================================================================================================================================================================================================
|  0 | CREATE INDEX STATEMENT   |                      |         |      |         2 |     +4 |     1 |        1 |      |       |       |       |       |       |          |                            |
|  1 |   INDEX BUILD NON UNIQUE | MYTABLE_IDX_MYCOLUMN |         |      |         2 |     +4 |     1 |        1 |      |       |       |       |       |       |    25.00 | Cpu (1)                    |
|  2 |    SORT CREATE INDEX     |                      |    100K |      |         4 |     +2 |     1 |      10M | 3656 | 192MB |   795 | 192MB |   75M |  202M |    75.00 | Cpu (2)                    |
|    |                          |                      |         |      |           |        |       |          |      |       |       |       |       |       |          | direct path write temp (1) |
|  3 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL    | MYTABLE              |    100K |   46 |         1 |     +4 |     1 |      10M |  248 | 120MB |       |       |       |       |          |                            |
========================================================================================================================================================================================================
```

I expect you'll see some "weird" events.  Perhaps some sort of table lock because some other process is locking the table.

If it's just a massive table and it takes hours to read it, then parallelism might help.  Here's the simplest way to make it work.  Tuning parallelism can be difficult, but if you're lucky and everything is configured sanely, just adding the keyword `parallel` works great.

```
--Create index in parallel.
create index myTable_idx_myColumn on myTable(myColumn) parallel nologging;
--Reset it to NOPARALLEL after it's done.
alter index myTable_idx_myColumn noparallel;
```

Comment: Thanks much for the response!  The result of the first operation is that the table is about 9.5GB.  However, I haven't been able to do the second part because dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor didn't work from dbVisualizer (ORA-00904: "DBMS_SQLTUNE"."REPORT_SQL_MONITOR": invalid identifier) and I don't have direct access to the server, but our DBA said he'd be able to look into it next week.  I'll try to keep this up to date for others who have similar issues.